# Error: ' module cordova/plugin_list not found'

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am very new to AnjularJS and mobile development. Currently in our mobile application, we have an option for users to signup into our app using their Twitter account.

I have followed the twitter authentication of an awesome tutorial by Simon.. the link is here...
http://blog.ionic.io/displaying-the-twitter-feed-within-your-ionic-app/

When I try to login using Twitter, I am getting the following error.... ' module cordova/plugin_list not found'

Could anybody you please help me to get out of this issue...
Any help appreciated..

Thanks,
Satya

Comment: Did you find solution for this, I am facing the same error?

Comment: @GerardvandenBosch I tried to access the mobile app home page from web browser, so I faced the above problem. When I launched the same app in emulator/mobile its working fine.